# Cronjob saving files

Tags: cron, cpanel

I have the following cronjob command:
`/usr/bin/wget http://domain/cron/cache.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

this command saves and logging in my home directory `cache.php` files for each cronjob, and each one runs every mintue!

How I can prevent it from logging/saving?

Comment: Ultimate Cron uses the last log entry to determine when the job last ran. Meaning that if you discard the logs, the job will run too often, since it think it hasn't run yet. Source:- Is it possible to disable logging completely for a particular cron job? [#2384461] | Drupal.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do? `wget http://domain/cron/cache.php` will download that file and save it in the current working directory.

If you just want to make the request but not save the file, you need to tell `wget` to output to stdout with `-O-`:

```
wget -O- 'http://domain/cron/cache.php' &> /dev/null
```

See [man wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Logging-and-Input-File-Options) for options.